# How to make a shadless material that would allow shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, shadows

I've been successful to achieve shade less material in Blender by following set up:

[image]

but is there any way we can allow these materials to cast shadows? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use all caps in the titles of your questions. An object that has this sort of material assigned to it still casts shadows. I assume you wish to make a shadeless material that would receive flat 'shadless' shadows, is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry for using caps. yes, i did mean shadeless materials that would be able to receive shadows. my bad

Comment: not quiet. it has shading onto itself. but looks helpful, thanks for the link!